# no puedo instalar java en ubuntu 19.10

Tags: java

tanto java 8 como 11. me lanzan esto en la terminal:
El paquete «oracle-java11-installer» no tiene un candidato para la instalación

Comment: Eso se debe seguramente a que ya tienes instalada otra versión basura de java que no es la que deberias tener para tu sistema operativo, me ocurrio una vez pero no recuerdo si fue en ubuntu o kali linux, el tema es que hacer la descarga directa desde la pagina oficial de java sin saber exactamente cual requieres te da un java que no cumple los requisitos para poder que se ejecute de manera correcta en distros basadas en debian.

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10?, ubuntu experimental, ya logro entender cual es el problema, creo que no hay una distribuición oficial de java para ese sistema aún, te descargaste la versión mas nueva de ubuntu.

Comment: se que esto no tiene que ver con programacion pero ayudenme por favor .siempre me sale esto :(ocurrio un error con el gestor de paquetes) y aparece un circulo rojo con una linea blanca atravesada en la parte de arriba

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo desinstalar por completo todas las versiones que tienes de java e intentar instalarlo desde la terminal y no desde la pagina web oficial como tal, intenta lo siguiente a ver si te sirve:

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-19-10-eoan-ermine-linux